# TypeError: string indices must be integers (dictionaries)

Tags: python, dictionary

When I tried to run this code I'm getting a `TypeError` like this:

```
items[i[id]] = i
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And here is my code:

```py
x = {
    '1': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 2
    },
    '2':{
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Pizza',
        'price': 15,
        'quantity': 5
    },
    '3': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 5
    },
}
items = {}
counter = 0
for i in x:
    if items:
        for j in items:
            if j['id'] == i['id']:
                j['quantity'] = j['quantity'] + i['quantity']
                counter = 1
    else:
        items[i[id]] = i

    if counter != 1:
        items[i[id]] = i
print(items)
```

Comment: The most probable syntax for what you want to do is `items[i]['id']` however that still doesn't work. What are you trying to create in the `items` variable ? another dictionnary ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its an easy fix, Use .values() to get the values of the key value pairs,
like : `for i in range x.values():`
Here is the corrected code :

```
x = {
    '1': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 2
    },
    '2':{
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Pizza',
        'price': 15,
        'quantity': 5
    },
    '3': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 5
    },
}
items = {}
counter = 0
for i in x.values():
   if items:
        for j in items.values():
            if j['id'] == i['id']:
                j['quantity'] = j['quantity'] + i['quantity']
                counter = 1
   else:
       items[i['id']] = i
   if counter != 1:
       items[i['id']] = i
print(items)
```

Output :

```
{1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'Burger', 'price': 10, 'quantity': 7}, 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'Pizza', 'price': 15, 'quantity': 5}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to obtain a new dict, unified on `id` value and a new `quantity` is a sum of all quantities with that `id`. If we suppose that `id` and `quantity` are always present at `x` values and `quantity` is an integer, you can do it this way:

```py
x = {
    '1': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 2
    },
    '2':{
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Pizza',
        'price': 15,
        'quantity': 5
    },
    '3': {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Burger',
        'price': 10,
        'quantity': 5
    },
}
items = {}
counter = 0
for key, item in x.items():
    if item['id'] in items:
        items[item['id']]['quantity'] += item['quantity']
    else:
        items[item['id']] = item
print(items)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'Burger', 'price': 10, 'quantity': 7}, 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'Pizza', 'price': 15, 'quantity': 5}}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `id` is a built-in function in Python. In your code, you never set the variable `id` to anything else, so `id` is still this built-in function. Also, when you write `for i in x`, where `x` is a dictionary, `i` is a *key* to this dictionary, and this key is a string. These two things together explain your error.

In the following code:

```py
items[i[id]] = i
```

the Python interpreter attempts to use `id` as an index into the string `i`. This doesn't work because `id` is a function, not an integer, hence the resulting `TypeError`.

As others have noted, you probably meant to write `i['id']`, not `i[id]`. Furthermore, you probably meant for `i` to be one of the values in the dictionary `x`, not one of its keys.